# Parse Saved HTML file content in Python like HTML Request response

Tags: python

I can parse a web page in python when accessing the url via requests package 
however I’d like to parse this same web page in python when accessing from a file using the same bulk of parsing code but having an issue with processing from file , getting the top parent object into the same type as the web request object.

I can parse a web page in python when accessing the url via requests package thus:

```
xreq  = requests.get('some url')
xreqtree = html.fromstring(xreq.content)
```

However I’d like to parse this same web page in python when accessing from a file doing thus:

```
f = open("someurlsfile.html", "r", encoding="utf-8")
xftreetmp = etree.parse(f)
f.close
xftree = xftreetmp.getroot()
```

At this point, both start at root elements html however the request is of type `lxml.html.HtmlElement` but the file is of type `lxml.etree._Element`. I would like to open the file and get it into the `lxml.html.HtmlElement` type to that I can have one set of parsing code for the page.

Comment: if you want it the same, why are you doing totally different things with the first and the second? You could always read the file into a string and run your `html.fromstring` function on that.

Comment: btw where does `html.fromstring` come from? it's not in the stdlib - the closest i can find is `xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring`

Comment: Reading the file will produce a string so just process it the same. `xftree  = html.fromstring(f.read())`